# LightSwitch disable screen while loading

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm implementing a custom search screen with a ComponentOne GridView. All works well except while paging, searching, sorting the controls vanish. They're back in a second when the data is loaded.

When using the standard search screens the screen is disabled and a icon appears in the middle indicating the screen is loading.

My question, can this behavior be used in custom screens?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Your custom control would have to get a bit "cleverer" regarding asynchrony.  Have the control display its grid and other controls immediately upon load.  Then have a canvas to overlay the control giving it that greyed out visual effect.  Then load the data asynchronously.  Once the data is loaded, the callback should change the visibility of the canvas to remove the greyed out effect, and bind the grid to the retrieved data.

Comment: I've given up on Lightswitch and switched to WPF. In LS the easy things are real easy, the harder stuff is near imposible. Unless time isn't an issue and it usually is. But thanks anyhow.